# Calculating the area of a hexagon (6-sided entity) alternative

Tags: polygons

I am kinda curious in something. When looking at a hexagon (6-sided entity) and wanting to calculate the area, could you in theory treat the hexagon as 4 triangles and one square in the middle like this?

[image: hexagon]

Here is my calculations, if this can be done
$\left(\frac{C×A/2}{1/2}×4\right) + (B×A)$

Comment: You should be dividing C x A/2 by 2 not by 1/2 to get area of one of the four triangles. Another note is your hexagon is not a "regular" hexagon without some conditions on A,B,C.

Comment: I see that, sorry, I am not very familiar with the LaTex formatting.
Second of, what are you referring to when you say "conditions"?

Comment: @coffeemath Furthermore, just a sidenote. You can just "rotate" the hexagon to get the "regular" hexagon. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: In your drawing, if you keep A and B like they are, and make C shrink toward zero, you can easily see it won't be a regular hexagon. Een rotating it won't change that. By the way "regular" hexagon means all six sides have same length. So that would impose some limits on what A,B,C can be to make it regular.

Comment: In the latex for your formula with the longer fraction line, there is a \frac followed by two expressions in curly brackets, and in the second of these you now have 1/2. Just edit and change that to a 2 to fix it.

Comment: @coffeemath I see, I misunderstood what you meant with "regular" hexagon, pardon me for that. Could you also elaborate what you mean with "conditions"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131036/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-nemanja-vuksanovic).